# Как убрать не нужные метаданные в результате методов find() в YII

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Как убрать не нужные метаданные в результате методов find()? А то такой ужас ни на клиент передавать нет желания ни в сессии хранить.

Answer (score 1):

После `$model->find()`

`$dataForClient = $model->attributes`

возвращает массив с данными

Comment: Это если с одной моделью работать, т.е. с одной таблицей базы. А если запрос реляционный?

Comment: тогда, наверное, руками наполнять собственный массив при помощи $model->attributes и foreach($model->otherModels as $otherModel){}